# PDO fetchObject() after fetchall(). returning false

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PHP.
I am trying to display the details of employees in form of table.
But `while($row = $result->fetchObject())` part is not executing, as `$result->fetchObject()` is returning false. Has it something to do with `$rows = $result->fetchAll();`?
Here's the code snippet.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, designation FROM employees";

if ($result = $pdo->query($sql)) {
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();
    $num_rows = count($rows);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table>\n";
        echo " <tr class=\"heading\">\n";
        echo " <td>ID</td>\n";
        echo " <td>Name</td>\n";
        echo " <td>Designation</td>\n";    
        echo " </tr>\n";

        while($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
            echo " <tr>\n";
            echo " <td>" . $row->id . "</td>\n";
            echo " <td>" . $row->name . "</td>\n";
            echo " <td>" . $row->designation . "</td>\n";
            echo " </tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "No employees in database.";
    }

else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . print_r
    ($pdo->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: When you call `fetchAll()`, you've already fetched everything!  So, `fetchObject()` has nothing left to fetch.  Just loop over `$rows`.

Comment: ... as in `foreach ($rows as $row)` in place of the `while()` loop. You may also need to set the fetch type when you call `fetchALL()` if you did not set its default:  `$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`.  Then you don't need to change anything inside the loop body.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You should post that as an anaswer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PDO's documentation is a little confusing on this, but the [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method and its cousin `fetchAll()` return `false` when no more rows are available to return.  The docs say it returns `false` *on failure*, and a lack of available rows counts as a failure.

Your initial call to `fetchAll()` gets all the rows from the `PDOstatement` result object and there are no more for the `fetchObject()` call to retrieve so it returns `false`.

You only need your initial call to `fetchAll()`, but you may need to set its fetch type to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` if you did not previously set the default fetch type for your connection.

Then, you can replace your `while` loop with a simple `foreach` loop over the `$rows` array you already have. This has the added benefit of separating your display logic from your database query business logic a little more:

```
if ($result = $pdo->query($sql)) {
    // Fetch them now, as objects
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $num_rows = count($rows);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table>\n";
        echo " <tr class=\"heading\">\n";
        echo " <td>ID</td>\n";
        echo " <td>Name</td>\n";
        echo " <td>Designation</td>\n";    
        echo " </tr>\n";

        // $rows now has everything you need, just loop over it
        foreach ($rows as $row {
            echo " <tr>\n";
            echo " <td>" . htmlspecialchars($row->id) . "</td>\n";
            echo " <td>" . htmlspecialchars($row->name) . "</td>\n";
            echo " <td>" . htmlspecialchars($row->designation) . "</td>\n";
            echo " </tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "No employees in database.";
    }

else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . print_r
    ($pdo->errorInfo());
}
```

Note also, that I added calls to `htmlspecialchars()` while writing output to HTML.  That is always recommended, so that characters like `< > &` which have special meaning in HTML are properly encoded, and avoids cross-site scripting vulnerabilities if those values originated as user input.