# PHP login returning false with correct user name?

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to create a basic login form which would check the user input against the database and respond accordingly.

Here is the main if statement:

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) { //sets $email and $pw to what the user types
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pw = $_POST['pw'];

        $user_ID = login($db, $email, $pw);
        if ($user_ID) {
            $id = $user_ID->user_ID;
            echo "<p>$id Login success!</p>";
            header("Location: index.php?page=profile&id=$id");
            die();
        }else {
            echo "<p>Login Failed</p>";
            echo $email;
            echo $pw;
            echo $user_ID;
        }
    }
```

and the function:

```
    function login($db,$email, $pw) {
        $inc_pw = md5($pw);
        $sql = "SELECT user_ID FROM profile WHERE email = '$email' AND pw = '$inc_pw'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        return $result->fetchObject();
    }
```

At present it always returns false and therefor Login failed. As far as i can tell it is not properly comparing the email and pw with what’s in the database but i am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you checked `echo $sql`?

Comment: Please note that using an md5hash to store passwords is considered insecure.

Comment: Please read through [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and begin learning to use `prepare()/execute()` as appropriate for your chosen database API. You have a SQL injection vulnerability here in `$email` which would actaully allow anyone to login with any password or no password

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wondering if an answer you gave http://stackoverflow.com/a/21124463/ may be what the OP also needs to do or be of help. Found it via Google search => "fetchObject()".

Comment: I am well aware this is insecure. I am learning PHP and the teacher said we wont worry about security at the moment. It is something we will learn at a later stage once we have got the basics.

Comment: @DavidHirst Is this PDO you are using? (`fetchObject()` suggests it is). Enable exceptions on your PDO object `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so if the query itself failed, PDO will trip.  If it just doesn't return rows (fetchObject() is false), then the query didn't match anything and you must carefully debug the table rows vs the values you input.

Comment: Why waste time with MD5 (old, unsafe and broken) and trying to figure this out, when you can use this http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp which uses PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`.

Comment: (I would add that security _is the basics_! We see too often around here that it never gets revised, so we always point it out) :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Surprised a google search would turn up a low-votes question with only 1100 views

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Second result right under PHP ;) not bad at all.

Comment: @DavidHirst If you're still working on this, inspect the SQL with `echo $sql;` and run that statement in a MySQL client program (the mysql CLI, phpmyadmin, Workbench, etc) to make sure it returns rows _in isolation_ from your PHP code. The MD5 strings in the table may not as expected, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my database. The function is searching for an encrypted (md5) password and the database contained only none encrypted password.

Comment: Then you should seriously consider encrypting your passwords in the database!

Comment: They are now. This is for an extremely rushed uni assignment and they are not doing a very good job of teaching us :(. Encryption and security are the least of our worries.