# PHP PDO fetchObject() returns no data but website loads correctly

Tags: php, pdo

I have been using these two pages for reference and to make sure I am doing this right since I am new to PDO and trying it out.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

[PDO fetchObject() after fetchall(). returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124156/pdo-fetchobject-after-fetchall-returning-false)

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to fetch all columns from the table 'players' which has a uid equal to the posted one. (I know there will only be one row returned).

Then I need to display only a few certain columns from that row.

**editPlayer.php (code snippet)**

```
$uidPlayer = $_POST['hidden'];

include '../verifyPanel.php';
include '../header/examinerheader.php';

masterconnect();

$sqlPlayer = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE uid=?";
$stmt1 = $db->prepare($sqlPlayer);
$stmt1->execute($uidPlayer);
$player = $stmt1->fetchObject();

$username = $player->name;
$uidPlayer = $player->uid;
$pid = $player->playerid;
```

`masterconnect();` contains the `$db` which is the connect details and a global variable.

using echo on `$username` does not show a value at all/

I would appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument of `execute` is **array**:

```
$stmt1->execute([$uidPlayer]);
```

Comment: I thought that was to allow an array of variable for the prepared statement? I tried your recommendation and you are correct though. Thank you.